# Display attribute data in password-recovery-notify.jsp

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In Identity Server 5.10, if we have login based on a custom username field, how can I have the password-recovery-notify.jsp still display the email address (obfuscated) that the recovery email went to as part of the 'Password.recovery.information.sent.to.the.email.registered.with.account' response?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the password-recovery-notify.jsp page to retrieve and display the obfuscated email address.

Locate the password-recovery-notify.jsp file in the Identity Server deployment directory. It's usually found in <IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint/.
Edit the JSP to include logic to display the obfuscated email address. This will involve reading the request attribute set by the notification sending module and displaying it within the Password.recovery.information.sent.to.the.email.registered.with.account message or as a separate message.